# Fragment layout loading delay

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, slidingdrawer

As per the answer here [How to make fragments load faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370286/how-to-make-fragments-load-faster) I put all tasks in an async task and still there's a delay while loading fragment. The fragment is a calculator, with 30 buttons and two text views.

I have a sliding drawer and the delay occurs when I choose the item that opens the calculator fragment. The sliding drawer lags while returning to hidden position.

I use `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, calc_frag)` in a fragment activity to load the fragment.

I removed all the code in the fragment except inflating the layout. Lag.

How I get rid of the delay/lag?

Answer (score 0):

Without code its hard to say, maybe you should look at [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) and hold on showing the fragment until the contents have fully loaded?

Comment: I did that. The drawer closes with lag and then the progress dialog is shown.